# Delete specific row in Excel that's not continue

Tags: microsoft-excel

i need some help to delete specific lines for example, lines 31, 62, 124 and continue until 3000+ in Excel, it's a mutiplication of 31. Can anyone help me ? I'm using excel 2016.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need a helper column:

In the first cell of the helper column put this formula `=MOD(ROW(),31)`. Fill down this formula to all the rows.

In rows 31, 62, 93, etc the value of the helper column will be 0.

Go to Filter, a little triangle will appear on top of the columns. Click on the one in the helper column.

Select 0 and deselect all the other values.

Now the sheet shows **only** the rows 31,62,39,etc. Select the rows, right-click and choose delete rows.

Go to filter again and select all values and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Take this short macro:

```
Sub Kill31()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    N = 9999
    For i = N To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(i, 1).Row Mod 31 = 0 Then
            Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

replace the *9999* with the bottom of your data and run it *(in your case, 4000 may be okay)*